# Is a matrix simply a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, logic

I came across matrixes while looking into AI Algorithms and wondered what they are. I've seen a post on another forum saying it is a rectangular array. So is it a 2D array for example like this?:

```
 array{ 
        {0,0,0,0}
        {1,1,1,1}  
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but they include most of the time some rules about how to add and multiply matrices.

Not all matrices out there actually use these addition / multiplication rules - for example, image data is often held in "matrices" (in, e.g., openCv) even though there's no sense using matrix multiplication for images.

So yes - most of the time you can think of matrices as 2D arrays, with sometimes a special multiplication rule between these arrays.

Comment: I would like to ask how multiplying and adding would work with matrices.

Comment: @silentcallz Adding works as you would expect (you add each element with the corresponding element of the other matrix. If your matrix is NxM, you can only add it to other matrices that are also NxM). Multiplication is more complicated - you can google "matrix multiplication" to see examples - and if your matrix is NxM it can only be multiplies by matrices that are MxK (for any K). Note that it means two rectangular matrices of same shape can't be multiplied with each other!

Answer (score 1):

Yes a matrix can be represented as a 2D array.
A 2D array can be represented as nested arrays, for example if you a table like this:

[image]

it could be represented as

> [ [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3] ]

then a[0][0] would correspond the the 0th position in the 0 indexed array